# Simple method for a HashMap seems correct but it is not working

Tags: java, class, oop, methods, hashmap

I'm getting a `NullPointerException`, when my `submittedAnswers()` method calls the `countAnswers()` method, but I have checked my `HashMap` and it contains the correct information. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (database.get(i).equals('A'))
```

error starts at ^^

```
private int countA, countB, countC, countD; // counters for the different answers
HashMap<Integer, Character> database = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();

public void countAnswers() 
{
    while(!database.isEmpty())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < database.size(); i++)
        {
            if (database.get(i).equals('A')) 
            {
                countA++;
            }
            if (database.get(i).equals('B'))
            {
                countB++;
            }
            if (database.get(i).equals('C')) 
            {
                countC++;
            }
            if(database.get(i).equals('D')) 
            {
                countD++;
            }
        }
    }
}
/*
 * checks if the student has submitted or not, if the student 
 * has then it removes the student and submits the new submittion, 
 * if not than just submits the student. then calls to counts the submitted answers
 */
public void sumbittedAnswers(int studentID, char answer) 
{

    if(database.containsKey(studentID))
    {
        database.remove(studentID);
        database.put(studentID, answer);
    }
    else
        database.put(studentID, answer);

    countAnswers();
}
```

Comment: What is null? database? database.get(i)?

Comment: the first if statment is where it starts, the submittedAnswers method works perfectly, its the countAnswers method thats giving me problems

Comment: how did you populate your HashMap?

Comment: @KickButtowski with my sumbittedAnswers method

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information. I would try calling each function to pinpoint what is null. Is it the get() function or equals() function that causes the nullpointer error? You want to check if objects != null before you dereference them or call methods on them.

Answer (score 2):

The get on a hashmap does not work like an array.

`database.get(i)` is not index i, it is get the Object key.

so unless your student id's are, 0,1,2,3,4 through to size-1 it won't work.

If you want to iterate over a hashmap you need to do something like this.

```
Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method in java.util.Map `get(V)` doesn't return the element at the position i (like in a List), but return the value which have the key == i, or null if there is no key == i.

So if your map has size == 10 and you write iterate from 0 to 9 the get method will return null if you haven't inserted any key-value which has that number for key.

Example

```
map.put(12, 'A');
map.put(22, 'B');

for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++)
  if(map.get(i).equals('A'))
```

the get will return null because you haven't put in the map any k-v with key == 0